# How to extract an array from array stack?

Tags: php, arrays, imap

I've got a set of arrays of string from **imap_fetchstructure**. But I can't extract the  string out of the set. I need the value of [filePath] so I've silly tried

`echo [attachments:protected][filePath];`

And it doesn't work at all. I'm so new to this kind of array... This is the sample of an array set.

By the way these lines are getting from this:

```
$mailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($this->getImapStream(), $mailId, FT_UID);
```

Which is `$this->getImapStream()` comes from a class [ImapMailbox.php](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap)

```
IncomingMail Object ( 
    [id] => 2687 
    [date] => 2014-08-07 16:53:11 
    [subject] => test attc 
    [fromName] => Hello Kitty 
    [fromAddress] => hello@kitty.com 
    [to] => Array (
        [sales@hellokitty.com] => sales 
    ) 
    [toString] => sales 
    [cc] => Array ( ) 
    [replyTo] => Array (
        [hello@kitty.com] => Hello Kitty 
    ) 
    [textPlain] => testing for attachment 
    [textHtml] => testing for attachment
    [attachments:protected] => Array (
        [487540462265330294] => IncomingMailAttachment Object  ( 
             [id] => 487540462265330294 
             [name] => america_support_taks.jpg 
             [filePath] => /home/hellokitty/domains/hellokitty.com/public_html/email/inc/2687_487540462265330294_america_support_taks.jpg 
       ) 
   )
)
```

Comment: What code generates this output?

Comment: There might be an accessor method for getting at the filename that you want to retrieve - what are you using to retrieve/generate this data?

Comment: Btw this object is **not** coming from `imap_fetchstructure`, compare to the return description in the manual.

Comment: The attachements property is protected, thus there must be a public getter. Try to access the filePath by `$incomingMail->attachements['487540462265330294']->filePath`

Comment: @SanderKoedood, it's from a class `ImapMailbox.php` which I already update the source. Please follow. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelD. It's not work, sorry :(

Comment: @DanFromGermany, Yeah technically it's not direct from `imap_fetchstructure` but it's the same method from a class. Please update the source. Thank you.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, the numbers in attachments is changing every time the page load - it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easy and the methods can be found in the [link you provided](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap/blob/master/src/ImapMailbox.php).

The attachments are a `protected` property of the `IncomingMail` object (see line 558) but a few lines further down there is a `public` method `getAttachments()` (line 567). The object `IncomingMailAttachment` has only 3 properties of which all are marked `public` (line 589).

```
$attachments = $mailStructure->getAttachments();

foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    // Array of IncomingMailAttachment objects
    echo $attachment->filePath;
}
```

Comment: Dan, Thank you very much. For an answer. The method works great after a little change from `getAttachements()` into `getAttachments()` - no 'e' after 'h'. :D

Comment: Dan, Thank you very much. Anyway I know that a silly question but again, thanks for your time.

Comment: It's not a silly question at all! I think the readers were just confused when you didn't link the library from github.